# Redirect http to https in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, redirect, https, asp.net-mvc-5

**I need to redirect from htttp://metroyapi.com.tr or/and "http://www.metroyapi.com.tr" to https://www.metroyapi.com.tr.**

I already tried the following methods but none of them worked.

At Startup:

```
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
        {
            if (context.Request.IsSecure) {
                await next();
            } else {
                var withHttps = Uri.UriSchemeHttps + Uri.SchemeDelimiter + context.Request.Uri.GetComponents(UriComponents.AbsoluteUri & ~UriComponents.Scheme, UriFormat.SafeUnescaped);
                context.Response.Redirect(withHttps);
            }
        });
```

At Global.asax:

```
if (!Context.Request.IsSecureConnection)
            Response.Redirect(Context.Request.Url.ToString().Replace("http:", "https:"));
```

and

```
if (!HttpContext.Current.Request.IsSecureConnection) {
            Response.Redirect("https://" + Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_HOST"]
                                         + HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl);
        }
```

At FilterConfig:

```
filters.Add(new RequireHttpsAttribute());
```

and bunch of web.config solution.

None of them worked I still get 404 error.

Any suggestions?

Help is much precited!

Comment: Did you look at this article? http://tech.trailmax.info/2014/02/implemnting-https-everywhere-in-asp-net-mvc-application/

Comment: I am going to do that.
Thank you!

Comment: I am sorry but i guess there is a misunderstanding and it is my fault. The redirect i like to do is as follows. 
I need to redirect from htttp://metroyapi.com.tr or http://www.metroyapi.com.tr to https://www.metroyapi.com.tr